# preg_match and RegEx to find number from HTML page

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Using preg_match function, I want to find the number 30899 from the following html string.

I've used the following line of code:

```
preg_match("/<a ?.* onclick=\"cms4i.models.dealersearch.view.navigate\('DETAIL', '(.*)'\);\" class=\"partner_name link\">Zentrum GmbH Standort<\/a>/i", $data, $matches);
```

It doesn't return any matching string, though $data has 30899 here.

$data variable is as follows:

```
<li class="partner_teaser clearfix">
  <div class="partner_gutter">
    <a href="#" onclick="cms4i.models.dealersearch.view.navigate('DETAIL', '30899');" class="counter link">01</a>
    <i class="icon_car" title="Partner (Verkauf)">Partner (Verkauf)</i>
    <i class="icon_spanner" title="Partner (Service)">Partner (Service)</i>
  </div>
  <div class="partner_summary">
  <a href="#" onclick="cms4i.models.dealersearch.view.navigate('DETAIL', '30899');" class="partner_name link">Zentrum GmbH Standort</a>
  <div>Franklinstraße 24</div><div>10587 City</div>
  <div>5,4 km</div>
  <a href="#" onclick="cms4i.models.dealersearch.view.navigate('DETAIL', '30899');" class="link link_a1">Auf Karte anzeigen</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Though I solved this kind of problems earlier, I can't find the solution how to find these numbers from this string. I believe an expert can find its solution quickly.

Comment: Well, first you need to escape your periods, otherwise, isn't it working for you? [Seems to work here](http://www.regex101.com/r/iP9bG1). Or is that you want to get all the `30899`?

Comment: Yes, your are right. Now, I've used \ to escape the periods. But, it doesn't return any matching string.

Comment: I guess it's the function then. Perhaps you might want to use the `g` flag in addition to the `i` flag you already used. Or `preg_match_all` like enenen suggested.

Answer (score 2):

As I see you are searching for number which is parameter in the `navigate` method. So, you can try with:

```
preg_match_all('/\.navigate\([a-zA-Z\,\s\']+([0-9]{3,})\'\);" class="partner_name link"\>Zentrum GmbH Standort\<\/a\>/', $html, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 30899
    [1] => 30899
    [2] => 30899
)
```

Then you can exclude repeated numbers if it's possible to have more than one unique number. If not, extract only one number, not all.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it returns all of different numbers displayed on those <li> tag. How can I find the number near to "Zentrum GmbH Standort". Please note the full html page contains hundreds of different number. I want to find specific number using 'class="partner_name link">Zentrum GmbH Standort</a>'.

Comment: I edited my answer. But if you want the number used in/near a html element then probably it would be better to use DOMDocument instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
preg_match('/<a (.*) onclick=/', $data);
```